# mailto: Navigation to the webpage was cancelled

Tags: internet-explorer

one of our apps puts an URL like the following one into the Internet Explorer's (10 or 11) address bar to compose a new Email:

```
mailto:?subject=Incident Ticket:%2000869696&body=%0ALink%20to%20Ticket:%0A<https://ourserver/arsys/forms%2Farse7%2FOurform%2FAdminstrator%2BView%2F%3Feid=00869696>
```

This works as expected, i.e. a new email opens in the standard email program. However it has an undesirable side effect: it opens a new IE window that says Navigation to the webpage was cancelled.

Ideas how to get rid of it? Chrome for instance closes that very new browser tab or window. Even an empty page would be cool but the error message raises questions among users.

Comment: I hate answers like this but, you *may* want to considering changing your approach to an email form. The problem with what you have is that it opens an email, and the user can easily delete/amend etc!

Comment: That's not a problem David, because in this case it's in the user's interest to not change anything.

Comment: I tested with Office Outlook as well as Mail App, but could not repro the problem in Windows 10/ IE 11. It's possible that the "URL Protocol" registry value is missing for mailto. (REF http://windowsxp.mvps.org/MailtoProtocol.htm)

Can post the registry export of HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mailto here?

Comment: These two keys:

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mailto`

and

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\mailto`